# Samsung device allocates memory on back navigation

Tags: android, out-of-memory, samsung-mobile

I have got a strange memory leak on samsung devices. If I do a lot of navigations then it produces an OutOfMemoryException with this StackTrace:

```
Exception: Failed to allocate a 276060 byte allocation with 184864 free bytes and 180KB until OOM
StackTrace:

--- End of managed Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError stack trace ---
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 276060 byte allocation with 184864 free bytes and 180KB until OOM
**at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:977)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:948)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:915)
at android.widget.TextView$MagnifierView.getContentsBitmap(TextView.java:14862)
at android.widget.TextView$MagnifierView.<init>(TextView.java:14806)
at android.widget.TextView.getMagnifierView(TextView.java:14707)**
at android.widget.Editor.onDetachedFromWindow(Editor.java:469)
at android.widget.TextView.onDetachedFromWindowInternal(TextView.java:6224)
at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:16766)
at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout(ViewGroup.java:5154)
at md58b29b5ebe7ec5add1ba4eaa7f6c6bb96.EventDetailsView_1.n_onDestroy(Native Method)
at md58b29b5ebe7ec5add1ba4eaa7f6c6bb96.EventDetailsView_1.onDestroy(EventDetailsView_1.java:47)
at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:7210)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1161)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4621)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4661)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap7(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1703)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Does anybody have an idea what these lines (See below) do and why the hell it allocates memory (Bitmap) when it is being destroyed?

```
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:977)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:948)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:915)
at android.widget.TextView$MagnifierView.getContentsBitmap(TextView.java:14862)
at android.widget.TextView$MagnifierView.<init>(TextView.java:14806)
at android.widget.TextView.getMagnifierView(TextView.java:14707)**
```

As far I understand from my testing, the activities are kept in memory even after `OnDestroyed` or `Finish` are called. If I navigate back and wait a minute I see the free memory is climbing again. Otherwise, the allocated memory get's bigger and at some point there is not enough space to do another navigation so the system tries to free memory by destroying an old activity. But this activity is allocating memory (MagnifierView) which isn't free during the Destroy-Process.

When I do the same on a Xperia Z5, the memory is freed right after a back navigation.

Comment: Do you use finish(); in your activity? Try to clean the bitmap variable when the Activity enter in onPause or onDestroy

Comment: Use android studio profiler to find what activity the memory leak is happening in

Comment: Unfortunately, these app is developed with Xamarin and the Inspector is not good as android studio. I would love to clean the Bitmap, but I have no idea where the magnifierview comes from and what it actually does.

Comment: I am looking at a same crash an have no idea why its happening.

Comment: Also coming across this issue, only seems to affect the A5 2017 (SM-A520F) running on 7.0. Anyone found a work around for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But I am very curious if someone knows the solution for this problem.

Comment: Looking at the crash rates on the Play Store, it seems like Samsung has fixed this in their Android 8.0 upgrade, released April 2018. All the crashes are still on 7.0/7.1, and the overall number has decreased by about 75%.